# Converting JSON structure gotten from Tracker to Esri JSON structure

Tags: python, json

I have JSON structure gotten from the Tracker:

```
{
    "16bec99d-a13e-4a21-a761-f673631b6060": {
    "ImageName": "chp/chp08.png",
    "Fill": 844168280,
    "Line": -11469736,
    "ID": "16bec99d-a13e-4a21-a761-f673631b6060",
    "ParentID": "94021e84-2a1e-440d-9f37-b349fa2cd0d8",
    "Name": "198008",
    "IsPolygon": true,
    "R": 0,
    "Lat": [
    58.496235,
    58.496299,
    58.49533,
    58.495213
    ],
    "Lng": [
    103.794173,
    103.797618,
    103.797715,
    103.796126
    ],
    "Holes": null
    },
    "8dc91f95-666e-4137-b29b-b12dbbddbdbe": {
    "ImageName": "chp/chp08.png",
    "Fill": 844168280,
    "Line": -11469736,
    "ID": "8dc91f95-666e-4137-b29b-b12dbbddbdbe",
    "ParentID": "94021e84-2a1e-440d-9f37-b349fa2cd0d8",
    "Name": "198005",
    "IsPolygon": true,
    "R": 0,
    "Lat": [
    58.484494,
    58.484392,
    58.483932,
    58.484163
    ],
    "Lng": [
    103.625914,
    103.626353,
    103.625889,
    103.625286
    ],
    "Holes": null
    }
}
```

I am intended to do it like this:

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "rings": [
          [
            [103.794173,58.496235],
            [103.797618,58.496299],
            [103.797715,58.49533],
            [103.796126,58.495213]
          ]
        ],
      },
      "attributes": {
        "Name": "123456",
        "ID": "16bec99d-a13e-4a21-a761-f673631b6060",
        "Fill": 844168280,
        "Line": -11469736
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "rings": [
          [
            [103.625914,58.484494],
            [103.626353,58.484392],
            [103.625889,58.483932],
            [103.625286,58.484163]
          ]
        ],
      },
      "attributes": {
        "Name": "689651",
        "ID": "8dc91f95-666e-4137-b29b-b12dbbddbdbe",
        "Fill": 844168280,
        "Line": -11469736
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use `json` module in Python (in jupyter notebook) for loading JSON file and get a dictionary. Here is my code:

```
import json 
data = json.load(tracker_data)
arc_json = {
      "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "rings": [x,y]

      },
        "attributes": data[d]
    } for x,y in zip(data[d]['Lng'],data[d]['Lat'])
  ]
}
```

The output isn't a thing I can be proud of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have achieved my aim and in case someone is looking for smth similar, here is my solution:

```
import json
#loading json object to our script
#after it's loaded, it's being in dictionary format
with open (path_to_your_json_file) as data_file:
json_data = json.load(data_file)

#script gets started in here
    arc_json={}
    geoAtr_lst=[]
    for d in json_data:
            feats={}
            feats['geometry']={}
            feats['geometry']['rings']=[list(map(list,zip(json_data[d]['Lng'],json_data[d]['Lat'])))]
            feats['attributes']={}
            feats['attributes']['Name']=json_data[d]['Name']
            feats['attributes']['ID']=json_data[d]['ID']
            feats['attributes']['Fill']=json_data[d]['Fill']
            feats['attributes']['Line']=json_data[d]['Line']
            geoAtr_lst.append(feats)
            arc_json['features']=geoAtr_lst
```

So, our result in arc_json variable:
[image]

Kind regards,
Sibdar